# Adding Vuetify to project template from vue-cli 3: Adding script tags to App.vue breaks the app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I'm a Vue noob and just need to understand something pretty basic. I'm used to vue-cli 3 where you have your "App.vue" and that's kind of your root component and of course you have your `<script>` and `<style>` tags in there like any other component. But when I start up a Vue project with vue-cli 3 and then do a `vue add vuetify`, App.vue no longer contains those tags and when I add them, the app breaks! Also there's a new folder called "views"? Can anyone break this down for me? I'm sorry to ask here but I can't find anything about it on Vuetify's page.

UPDATE:

Something strange happened when I tried to set up another project the same way --  everything looked like how I'm used to. That's with the following options selected after running `vue add vuetify`:

```
? Use a pre-made template? (will replace App.vue and HelloWorld.vue) Yes
? Use custom theme? No
? Use custom properties (CSS variables)? No
? Select icon font md
? Use fonts as a dependency (for Electron or offline)? No
? Use a-la-carte components? No
? Use babel/polyfill? No
? Select locale en
```

I realized that the `/views` folder came from having installed vue-router in that project, which I'm guessing may have had to do with the main `App.vue` file not accepting `<script>` or `<style>` tags? I'm going to revisit the vue-router docs but any additional input here would be much appreciated.

Comment: why don't use `npm install vuetify` and import it in ``main.js`

Comment: can you post the code that is now in App.vue, as well as any code that's in the new views folder?

Comment: `Use a pre-made template` answer it with no

Answer (score 1):

i see that `Use a pre-made template? (will replace App.vue and HelloWorld.vue)` question you answer it with `yes` and that will replace `app.vue` and `HelloWorld.vue`, so in the next time type `no` to answer it, you have to pay attention because they say `(will replace App.vue and HelloWorld.vue)`